# Guidelines for differences in Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I've looked for some guidelines on changes between earlier versions of Dynamics CRM (i.e. v.4 and v.2011) and the upcoming 2013. I couldn't find any, though. Does it mean no differences?(*irony!*)

It'd be a good thing to have as a reference when a customer decides to upgrade its system.

Comment: "To be expected" sounds like you're asking something that is extremely speculative, open ended *and* will become irrelevant within only a few months.

Comment: @Flexo Is your nickname by any chance a reference to a fantastic cartoon show now unluckily canceled? As for your explanation: good point - my formulation was unfortunate. It's been edited and completed so it won't become obsolete in any near future. (Upgrades from v.4, and definitely v.2011 will be done during the next few years, at least). Now grade be back up, Scotty! It hurts my ego when it says "minus anything". :D

Comment: The upcoming Polaris version is the first you should be worried about. I've seen it. It's nice but the users (some of them at least) will **not** appreciate that the ribbon is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for Crm 4 to 2011 I would suggest reading this MSDN article: [What's New for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 and Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309589.aspx).

For 2011 forward I would suggest just having a Google (as its going to keep changing), for terms like; mscrm, roadmap, polaris, orion.

This is a pretty good article: [Future stars: Dynamics CRM roadmap news from Las Vegas](http://niiranen.eu/crm/2012/10/future-stars-dynamics-crm-roadmap-news-from-las-vegas/)

Comment: I made a Google search but any reference of CRM 2013 but landed exclusively into CRM 2011 with combination with Office 2013. Polaris is a minor upgrade, isn't it? My understanding is that the changes to GUI are (almost) the only ones in it. Orion is news to me - I can google it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

See 
http://crm.dynamics.com/en-us/polaris

Looks like this is a Major release though MS are being very cautious about calling it CRM 2013.

Comment: It's my understanding that *Polaris* is the next version of GUI in *CRM 2011* and *CRM 2013*, while using the new GUI as well, will be the next version of the server engine itself. Since the switch from 4.0 to 2011 brought some changes to the coding and setup, it's my intention to be in the first row when 2013 is (pre)released.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lots of great info about changes in Dynamics CRM 2013 on this website :
http://dynamics.co.il